# How to get column name of data from RDS database as response in JSON in AWS Lambda Function using Nodejs

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

```
 "records": [
      [
        {
          "stringValue": "Smile Foundation2"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "Mumbai"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "+918600250073"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "Children"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "Alandi Pune ,411021"
        },
```

So I get this response but the key name is the same for all I want it as different.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Which API is this? What Database type? What is the Query?

Comment: I am writing lambda function in which I am firing a select query to fetch data from RDS database. In return I get the above response but the key to each value is same I want the key to be same as column name or any other key. I am writing code in javascript

Comment: Are you using a library to query the database directly from Lambda? If so may I know the library? And it helps if you post a similar query to debug.

Comment: No I am not using any library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a simple `select` query to fetch all the required `field names` and their `values`

I am adding a `Node.js` code below for reference that fetches data as `JSON` in response from database using `AWS Lambda Function`.

```
var mysql = require ('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool
({ 
    host     : 'your RDS endpoint',
    database : 'your database name',
    user     : 'your database username',
    password : 'your database password',
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>

{
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    
    pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) 
    {
    
        connection.query ("SELECT column_name FROM table_name", function(error, results, fields) 
        {
            connection.release();
            if (error) callback(error);
            else callback(null, JSON.stringify(results));
        });
  
  });
  
};
```

Comment: The key remains the same as stringValue when I get JSON response how can I get it?

Comment: Can you please share your code so that it would be much easier to reach the root cause?

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: @sarvesh pathak can you share the solution

Comment: @sarveshpathak why don't you share the solution?